# Mobx observe property of object in observe array

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have 2 class:

```js
class Account {
  games: Game[];
}

class Game {
  id: number;
  active: boolean;
}
```

And observable array of accounts.

I need to change property `active` in game using checkbox. But when I change `active` my react component will not update.

```js
interface GameListProps {
  games: Game[];
}

@observer
class GameList extends Component<GameListProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {Array.map((game) => (
          <div>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={game.active}
              onChange={(event) => {
                game.active = event.target.checked;
              }}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I change `active` with updating react component?

Can I create array of checed games but use `active` for `checked`?

```js
@observer
class GameList extends Component<GameListProps> {
  @ovservable checkedGames: number[];

  handleCheck(gameId: number, checked: boolean) {
    this.props.games.find((game) => game.id === gameId).active = cheched;
    if (checked) {
      this.checkedGames.push(gameId);
    } else {
      let findIndex = this.checkedGames.indexOf(gameId);
      if (findIndex !== -1) {
        this.checkedGames.splice(this.checkedGames.indexOf(gameId), 1);
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {Array.map((game) => (
          <div>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={game.active}
              onChange={(event) => {
                this.handleCheck(game.id, event.target.checked);
              }}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I think that it is not good because we change `props`. But we need game property `active` for init state of checkbox.

Comment: Can you share your observables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mark `active` property on the `Game` class as observable.

```js
class Game {
  id: number;
  @observable active: boolean;
  // --^
}
```